# Difficulties on trying to (re)install R

Tags: software-installation, dependencies, windows-subsystem-for-linux, r

I am trying to (re)install R in my ubuntu WSL. I already had done with

sudo apt install r-base-core
But, then, later I tried to change to R 4.0 with some compressed version. Eventually, the old R 3 version was uninstalled from my system and the R 4 was running.

Basically, I wanna work with DESeq2 and install some libraries like apeglm.

As I was having some issues I deleted/removed all the folders with R, including the ones in 'local/bin' and 'local/lib'.

Now, I'm trying again from scratch but I have the following:
[in]

```
sudo apt install r-base-core
```

[out]

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 r-base-core : Depends: zip but it is not installable
               Depends: unzip but it is not installable
               Depends: libpcre2-8-0 (>= 10.31) but it is not installable
               Recommends: r-recommended but it is not going to be installed
               Recommends: r-base-dev but it is not going to be installed
               Recommends: r-doc-html but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

If I try to install the depends, e.g., 'zip', I get the following:

[in]

```
sudo apt-get install zip
```

[out]

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package zip is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'zip' has no installation candidate
```

=======

edit: I've been through this: https://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/#install-r but it didn't work from this part on:

apt install --no-install-recommends r-base
The output is like the one before, saying I missing some depends...

edit 2: I posted this question originally at StackOverflow but an advanced user told me it would be a better idea to post it actually at askubuntu, so, here I am.

=======

I know that I have done several things wrong, but I really would appreciate it if someone could help me find some path here. I can provide more information/log if that's the case. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well I wouldn't claim to be an "advanced user" when it comes to this topic.  I just thought we might be more likely to find one over here ;-).  But sometimes folks are a bit fast on voting to close around here (on all Stack sites, really).  Sadly, the second linked answer is *very* old, and the answers there mostly out of date as far as I can tell.  The "Broken Packages" one, as I mentioned in a comment on your other question, may be more promising.