# Restoring the default repositories in WSL and reinstalling R

Tags: software-installation, dependencies, windows-subsystem-for-linux, r

I have made a similar question but it was closed here: [Difficulties on trying to (re)install R](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1368650/difficulties-on-trying-to-reinstall-r)

As I work in WSL I believe my situation is a bit specific.
After uninstalling R and going through some tutorials as the one suggested to me (in the closed question above) I am still not able to reinstall R in WSL.

Right now I'm stuck in this part of a tutorial described here [How do I restore the default repositories?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124017/how-do-i-restore-the-default-repositories) because in WSL "Softwares Sources" window will not popup like in regular ubuntu OS. Probably must have some way for one to do that update in the command line, but I haven't found it so far.

In case I want to update source, from this step on:

```
~$ sudo mv /etc/apt/sources.list ~/
~$ sudo touch /etc/apt/sources.list
~$ lsb_release -c -s
bionic
~$ ###### Ubuntu Main Repos
~$ deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main restricted universe multiverse

Command 'deb' not found, did you mean:

  command 'deb3' from deb quilt
  command 'debc' from deb devscripts
  command 'edb' from deb edb-debugger
  command 'dub' from deb dub
  command 'dex' from deb dex
  command 'xdeb' from deb xdeb
  command 'dab' from deb bsdgames
  command 'debi' from deb devscripts
  command 'dep' from deb go-dep
  command 'derb' from deb icu-devtools

Try: sudo apt install <deb name>
```

Some of my other logs:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
Hit:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/c2d4u.team/c2d4u4.0+/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:2 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu bionic-cran40/ InRelease
Hit:3 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu bionic-cran35/ InRelease
Hit:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/sublime-text-2/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
```

[Should I try to fix these 4 Hits?]

I have noticed that there is still a directory called R which I do not know if is causing any conflict with me trying to reinstall R (so, maybe should I delete it manually?).

```
/etc/R$ ls
Makeconf  Renviron.site  Rprofile.site  ldpaths  repositories
```

Finally, at /etc/apt/sources.list.d there are several files that I don't know either if I should manually delete them.

```
/etc/apt/sources.list.d$ ls
c2d4u_team-ubuntu-c2d4u4_0_-bionic.list  c2d4u_team-ubuntu-c2d4u4_0_-bionic.list.save  webupd8team-ubuntu-sublime-text-2-bionic.list  webupd8team-ubuntu-sublime-text-2-bionic.list.save
```

Thanks for the answers, in advance!

**FINAL EDIT**

HUGE thanks to https://askubuntu.com/users/1165986/notthedr01ds for giving me clues. Helped me figure that deb lines are not commands.

I'll describe briefly what solved my issue:

#1 created a new file of `sources.list` in Notepad adding this text [https://gist.github.com/h0bbel/4b28ede18d65c3527b11b12fa36aa8d1](https://askubuntu.com/users/1165986/notthedr01ds) on it. Because mine is Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS Bionic Beaver.
I've checked to not save the file as "sources.list.txt".

#2 moved the new sources.list to '/etc/apt/' by:

```
sudo mv /path/to/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list
```

#3 Done. As I was looking for an answer to allow me to reinstall R it solved my problem. BTW, I follow this installation of R from cran:

https://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/ and also troubleshooting from here:
https://github.com/stan-dev/rstan/issues/863

Comment: The `deb` lines aren't commands; they are lines that should be in your `/etc/apt/sources.list`.  However, I don't think that's your problem, even though someone marked it as a duplicate (but I'm not an `apt` expert by any means).  It seems more likely to me that the [other duplicate](https://askubuntu.com/q/223237/1165986).  I would suggest restoring your `/etc/apt/sources.list` (assuming that you backed it up as per the instructions), and then try some of the answers in the "Broken Packages" question.

Comment: I would start with the third answer down, personally -- `sudo apt-get autoremove` and see if that helps.